# redirect from subdomain to subfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to redirect from blog.mydomain.com/1/2/
to www.mydomain.com/blog/1/2/

I have the following rule in IIS7:

```
<rule name="New Blog Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^http://(?!www)(\w+)\.mydomain.com/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{C:1}/{C:2}" />
                </rule>
```

This does not seem to work.
When I enter http://blog.mydomain.com/test/, I get redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/test/

I do have a connonical URL rule, but I put this rule before it, so it should not get to it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The "(.*)" at the end of the input pattern will match any string. If you only want it to match something like "1/2", you will need to adjust the pattern accordingly.